# Background on Kontsevich's Work on Quantization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, mp.mathematical-physics

Where can I find background reading material necessary to be able to read about Maxim Kontsevich's work on quantization? I would like to able to follow the ongoing seminar of IHES, "Resurgence and Quantization" (which they have been posting [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJe032S6Tgo) of as the seminar goes on), but if this goal is too ambitious, I would at least like to be able to understand some of his earlier work, such as [Deformation Quantization of Poisson Manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9709040).

I know what a symplectic manifold and a Hilbert space is, and am aware of the physical motivation (the symplectic manifold corresponds to the "phase space" of classical mechanics, and the Hilbert space the state space of quantum mechanics). I know basics of algebraic geometry and algebraic topology, and some basic differential geometry in the context of mathematical physics (on the level of Mikio Nakahara's [Geometry, Topology, and Physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750306068)).

In particular, though, I am very interested in seeing how ideas from algebraic topology, algebraic geometry, homological algebra, and category theory play into the subject.